# Can I call my wife houri?

Tags: halal-haram, women, shirk, houri

I mean won’t it be some kind of shirk or haram to call my wife as a beautiful female creature from Jannah to make a compliment

Comment: What makes you think it would be Haram?

Comment: Idk, just only because it’s connected with Jannah, houris are mentioned in Quran, so probably it’s not right to make your wife compliments using such definitions

Comment: Well, if you call your wife, who is a human being I guess, a houri then it means you are uttering a lie. And lying is definitely Haram in Islam. Besides, I do not know anything from sunnah of the Prophet SAW whether he called his wives houris so that we could take an example from except he strongly admonished us to speak good and kind words to our wives. Maybe it depends on certain situation, circumstance.

Comment: I cannot tell that calling her houri with the purpose of saying she is beautiful can be considered as lie

Comment: Neither can I. As I said it depends on certain situation, circumstance. Can you calculate consequence with confidence taking into account all factors? Some women are too emotional, for instance. When you praise them they get proud, their wits become weak. Then Shaitan comes in and starts to whisper "You are beautiful, your husband should value this. He must be obedient to you. Force him...", and so on, and so on. One can imagine final consequence. Can we say in this situation your complement qualifies to be a lie?